# How to create a MariaDB connection in Activity Monitoring Console in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have created an amc database in MariaDB. I'm trying to create a connection to the amc database in Activity Monitoring Console(AMC) window of Talend Administration Center(TAC). I do not see MariaDB in the DB Type drop down list. and I'm getting the following error message. [image: Error message]

How can I connect to MariaDB from AMC?

Answer (score 0):

You need this driver:

`mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar`

See [this](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/How+to+install+MySQL,+Oracle+and+MS+SQL+drivers+for+Talend+Administration+Center) help file for more info.

Comment: I already have this driver in my <apache-tomcat>/webapps/org.talend.administrator/WEB-INF/lib